# Output of R code to display in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have some basic r code like:

```
setwd('C:/Users/usa/Desktop/abc_Feb7')
dupli<-read.csv(file='dupli_oppo.csv',head=TRUE)

dupli_1<-arrange(dupli,account_id,amount_opty)

dupli_2<-dupli_1 %>%
          group_by(account_id) %>%
   mutate(Diff = c(NA, diff(amount_opty)))
```

i want to get the dupli_2 output in Tableau. I used Rserve() package but then have no clue.

Comment: hi bunty, r u following the instructions from https://community.tableau.com/thread/236068?

Comment: yes i have already.But wondering how to accommodate my rcode inside SCRIPT_STR .

Comment: what to pass as sum in this case